# Evento DataGridView.CellClick

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Como posso usar o evento `DataGridView.CellClick` para dar o click em uma única coluna?

Do jeito que eu fiz no meu código se eu clicar em qualquer parte do datagrid ele faz a ação, e não queria que fosse deste jeito quero clicar um e uma coluna especifica e realizar a ação.

Segue o meu código do evento:

```
private void DGW_chklist_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = this.DGW_chklist.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    this.txt_nota.Text         = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    this.txt_cliente.Text      = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    this.txt_transp.Text       = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    this.txt_volume.Text       = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();

    ncheklist();
    if (txt_dtinicial.Text != "")
    {
        consultartransp();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Erro");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só validar qual a coluna que foi clicada e retornar se não for a que você deseja.

```
private void DGW_chklist_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ColumnIndex != DGW_chklist.Columns["NomeDaColuna"].Index)
        return;

    DataGridViewRow row = this.DGW_chklist.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    this.txt_nota.Text         = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    this.txt_cliente.Text      = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    this.txt_transp.Text       = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    this.txt_volume.Text       = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();

    ncheklist();
    if (txt_dtinicial.Text != "")
    {
        consultartransp();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Erro");
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado deu certinho aqui.